# Jquery binding events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the handler bound to an event of an element fire the wrong result?  I would expect the click event of Div1 below to popup a dialog stating 'div1' but it popup's 'div2'.

I am new to this and I am scratching my head to work out why this is happening.  I would appreciate any help to explain.

Cheers,

Alex

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TestEvents</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Object Array
    var objToTest = [{ TabName: "div1" },
             { TabName: "div2"}];

    //Adds events to each div
    function TestWhatIsGoingOn(myObjToTest) {
         for (i in myObjToTest) {
             $('#' + myObjToTest[i].TabName).click(function() { TestResult('TabName: ' + myObjToTest[i].TabName); });
         }
     }

    function TestResult(message){
        alert(message);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        TestWhatIsGoingOn(objToTest);
    });

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #div1, #div2
    {
     border: solid thin black;
     height: 100px;
     width: 300px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id='div1'>div1; click here to show expected result: 'TabName: div1'</div>
    <div id='div2'>div2; click here to show expected result: 'TabName: div2'</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems a classic closure problem, because when you click on div (any) `i` variable has already reach the end of `for` loop (so it always prints the last value). Try to change like so

```
function TestWhatIsGoingOn(myObjToTest) {
    for (i in myObjToTest) {
       (function(i) {
           $('#' + myObjToTest[i].TabName).click(function() { TestResult('TabName: ' + myObjToTest[i].TabName); });
       )(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does this continue to produce the wrong value:function TestWhatIsGoingOn(myObjToTest) {
         for (i in myObjToTest) {
             var tn = myObjToTest[i].TabName;
             $('#' + tn).click(function() { TestResult('TabName: ' + tn); });
         }
     }

Comment: Thanks, after reading about closures I can see what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this section of code:

```
for (i in myObjToTest) {
    $('#' + myObjToTest[i].TabName).click(function() {
        TestResult('TabName: ' + myObjToTest[i].TabName);
    });
}
```

The trouble is that the value of `i` is not hard-coded into this section.  When the function runs, it will see what the current value of `i` is.  Since you have since incremented it to refer to your second tab, this function will always refer to the second tab.  This feature of Javascript is called a closure -- it closes in the value of `i`.

The easiest way around this is to use jQuery to bind to more than one object at once, and then evaluate based on the object clicked on:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').click(function(){
        alert('TabName: ' + this.id);
    });
});
```

This will do everything you want your code in the question to do.

In a real-world situation, you would probably need to give the divs a common class (e.g. `toClick`) and then use a jQuery class selector (`$('.toClick')`).

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is another way to tackle the problem.  I was tring to build a plugin and have the user pass in the id array of divs to use.  Reading about closure on google, I can see where I was going wrong.  cheers!